# MySQL Unique Combination Across Many Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to have a unique pairing of columns in `MySQL` however it can be in any order...

So if I have three columns

```
Person1 Person2 Person3
```

and they all are `FOREIGN` keys to a person and I want these only to be allowed once in the table...

The row:

```
1 2 3
```

is the same as

```
3 2 1
```

is the same as

```
2 3 1
```

etc etc...so just doing `UNIQUE(Person1, Person2, Person3)` does not accomplish this task I do not think.

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting and voting to close. I think this is an interesting question.

Comment: the first idea coming to my mind: you need another column with ordered ids saved. or you should check an order while `INSERT` or `UPDATE`

Answer (score 0):

My solution (given this schema) would be to make the order predictable. The easiest way is to store them in descending order so that the first row always contains the smallest value and so on. This makes it easier to query and you will not be able to add two rows with the same members.

Since your question is pretty generic, my answer is vague. If you provide an example of what you are trying to accomplish, there might be better ways. In my experience, when you find yourself having columns representing the same type of relation it's often better to normalize. Going from friend1, friend2, ... friendN to a table of friends per user, for example.